# Flutter: Returning User/Device Recognition

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm looking for something that will recognize the device when reinstalling the app. There is IDFA for iOS and Android ID for Android, but I don't want to use it because permission is required. Whether users allow it or not, I need to query whether their device has used my app before.

I tried Shared Preferences.
I tried the Path Provider.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need permission to get ANDROID_ID (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID)

Comment: But I need permission for IDFA. I need solution for IOS & Android.